# Редирект с httpS на http

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите редирект для пренаправлдения всех страниц сайта, при изменении протокола с сохранением структуры.
те
- https: //www.site.ru/catalog/ -->301--> http: //www.site.ru/catalog/

пробовал как с указанием порта, так и условия от противного !=

Всем спасибо!!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Если не получиться попробуйте поместить их между `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` то что выше `</IfModule>`

Если и так не получиться то замените стоку `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` на вот эту строку `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$`

Ну или попробуйте php код

```php
<?php 
if  ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) 
        { 
                $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
                $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
                $good_url = "http://" . $host . $request_uri; 

                header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
                header( "Location: $good_url" ); 
                exit; 
        } 
?>
```

Comment: Никак не сработало(  А есть добавить php код сервер отдает 500

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Nginx Вы можете воспользоватся директивой **return код_состояния url**.
Для перевода схемы с сохранением url:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  location / {
    return http://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
  }
}
```

> Переменная **$request_uri** путь запроса к Вашему ресурсу
>   Директива return может быть задана на уровне контекстов **server, location, if**.